# Finding Max Revision

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table similar to the below:

```
REQ     PO      LINE    COST    REV
101630  P101630 1       26.48   0
101630  P101630 2       26.82   0
101630  P101630 3       17.83   0
101630  P101630 1       26.48   1
101630  P101630 2       110.00  1
101630  P101630 3       17.83   1
101630  P101630 1       52.96   2
101630  P101630 2       110.00  2
101630  P101630 3       35.66   2
```

How would I find the result I want would be something like this:

```
REQ     PO      LINE    COST    REV
101630  P101630 1       52.96   2
101630  P101630 2       110.00  2
101630  P101630 3       35.66   2
```

I tried using this but it didn't return correct results

```
select  req, po, line, cost, max(rev)
from table
where po= 'P101630'
group by req, po, line, cost
```

Comment: Next time please add some effort into formatting your questions. And please include what you attempted and/or what's wrong with your code.

Comment: What have you tried until now?  Please format output in your question

Comment: Have a look at `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: sorry, trying to figure out how format the tables!

Comment: Are you trying to find the last revision of each line or the lines of the last revision (assuming lines can be removed in newer revisions)?

Comment: latest revision of each line for req/po

Answer (score 3):

I would use (if you want last revision for each single REQ, PO, LINE):

```
SELECT  REQ, PO, LINE, COST FROM (
    SELECT REQ, PO, LINE, COST, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION REQ, PO, LINE BY ORDER BY REV DESC) AS RN
    FROM TABLE ) A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REQ, PO, LINE ORDER BY REV DESC) AS rw, REQ, PO, LINE, COST, REV 
FROM #T1 ) x
WHERE rw = 1
```

use row number to get only the highest rev

Comment: what if you dont know what the highest rev is?  what it it went to say 6?

Comment: @Kay_e_n, look at the `DESC` in this SQL. Highest becomes lowest, becomes 1.

Comment: That's why it's ordered by rev descending. Those with the max revs will have 1 as their rw @Kay_e_n

Comment: Still wrong. Either you filter by a specific PO or you add PO to the PARTITION BY clause

Comment: It's currently giving me the correct output as per OP's post. While we can discuss which columns should be included in the partition; it would be difficult to know exactly what would be needed to be there as per OP's sample data. I've no qualms adding PO to the columns in partition by, if he does have to consider a diff PO as a diff group.

Comment: As per OP's latest comment, he does need latest revision for each line for req/po. so yeah we should include po on the partition by

Comment: If the OP would have only a single `po` value he would not filter it in is query (`where po= 'P101630'`). Your query will return wrong results for more than one 'po'.

Comment: This issue is not related to OP's latest comment. For the other option ROW_NUMBER wouldn't work.

Comment: OP commented "latest revision of each line for req/po" so that basically confirmed to me that he does need to treat diff po as a diff group. I've already added PO to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Now it is the same as @etsa answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TABLE t1
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT REQ,PO,LINE,MAX(REV) AS REV
            FROM TABLE
           )t2
ON t1.REQ=t2.REQ
   AND t1.PO=t2.PO
   AND t1.LINE=t2.LINE
   AND t1.REV=t2.REV
```

Update: Optimal Query

Learn more about [RANKING FUNCTIONS](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/09/sql-server-2005-sample-example-of-ranking-functions-row_number-rank-dense_rank-ntile/)

```
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT REQ, PO, LINE, COST, REV, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REQ, PO, LINE ORDER BY REV DESC) AS rw
FROM TABLE)
SELECT REQ, PO, LINE, COST, REV
FROM CTE
WHERE rw = 1
```

Comment: This is not an optimal solution. Use analytic functions instead.

Comment: Yes, that is how to do it. It's just that at least two other people had answered with such a query more than 1 hour before you added it. Making it a CTE does not really add value either.